# Magento2 get attribute of product in price template default.phtml

Tags: magento2, price

In Magento 1, I was able to get attibute value with following code:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_id, 'att_price', $_storeId)
```

How can I get the value in Magento 2, in tempalte

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

I copied it to my theme:

```
/app/design/frontend/xxx/ddd/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

Thanks for the help!
Martin

Answer (score 0):

**In Magento 2 Get Attribute Raw Value Like This :-**

```
$protected $_resourceProduct;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resourceProduct)
         {
             $this->_resourceProduct = $resourceProduct;
         }

         public function getData()
         {

            $value = $this->_resourceProduct->getAttributeRawValue($productId,'attribute_name',$store_id);
         }
```

Comment: Thanks. But from where do I get $productId?

Comment: in your phtml file you can get product id using object manager

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');

Comment: or another option is to override the amount.php file and add your custom function for get current product data

Comment: Thanks! But echo $product->getId(); returns error?

Comment: try this $product->getData()

Comment: echo $product->getData('att_code'); returns error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95215/discussion-between-rk-rathod-and-matin).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
echo $block->getSaleableItem()->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getSaleableItem());
```